# ensuring unique sections in a string using JavaScript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that is of the following form: AB-CD-EF-GH. Here, AB, CD, EF, GH each constitute a section of the string. So in our above example, there are 4 sections. Now, I am trying to design a regex pattern that will ensure that all the sections of the string are unique. I am successfully able to capture characters of the string and even create capture groups but struggling to match the data inside the capture group in the pattern itself.
Can anyone please suggest as to how should I approach this problem?
Even a simple pattern would be a great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^(.+?)-(?!\1)(.+?)-(?!\1|\2)(.+?)-(?!\1|\2|\3)(.+?)$`

It's a little long-winded, and as you add more strings to ensure uniqueness, this regex grows exponentially. However, this regex will do the trick for your example. It uses negative lookaheads to ensure that none of the new matches are equal to the old matches.

[Try it here!](https://regex101.com/r/f0LPAB/3/)

Answer (score 2):

Testing if any of the sections is repeated is easier : `(\w\w).+\1` - https://regex101.com/r/PyrTlR/2

```js
console.log( /(\w\w).+\1/.test('AB-CD-EF-GH') )     // false

console.log( /(\w\w).+\1/.test('AB-CD-EF-CD') )     // true
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative could be to [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) on a hyphen and use [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to check if the number of the splitted parts are the same as size from the unique values of Set .

```js
let isUnique = s => {
  let splitted = s.split("-").filter(Boolean);
  return splitted.length === 4 ? (new Set(splitted)).size === splitted.length : false;
};

[
  "AB-CD-EF-GH",
  "AB-CD-EF-AB",
  "AB-AB-AB-AB",
  "AB-CD-EF-",
  "AB-CD",
  "AB-AB",
  "AB",
  ""
].forEach(s => console.log(s + " --> " + isUnique(s)));
```